# build and run not working andriod resource linking failed see the console for details

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

i created my new project for testing ads cause i have a project in which i have completed everything and then i tested it worked but after importing admob plugins  i had setup test ad then i treid to make apk it start making probelem in making and i tried [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF3JU.png)to use build and run it failed and there are 5 errors and 1 yellow error i downloded plugins from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v7.0.0 and there is a source code downloding option and there is hello worlds and then in scenes there is main scene

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue with my game. So, i realized that was the Admob plugin.

1 - **Try to downgrad or update your googleads unity plugin.** !!

```
The solution for me was to "DOWNGRADE" 
from googleads-mobile-unity v7.0.0 to googleads-mobile-unity v6.1.2
```

2 - **verify your key password**

3 - **try to force resolve android dependencies**, this plugin can help with it:
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

```
**After install plugin just:** Assets -> external dependency manager -> 
Android Resolver -> Force Resolver.
```

Cheers!